# Programs running on start that shouldn't be (Kubuntu)

Tags: kubuntu, startup

I have a weird problem that just started to occur recently. Every time that I boot my machine, two programs always open. My email client on my first virtual desktop and Firefox on my second desktop. It recently started happening and I have no idea why. I have checked autostart and there is nothing in there. It happens whether I properly shutdown the machine or do a hard shutdown.

How can I go about fixing this? I know it is a minor inconvenience, but it really irks me.

Result of `ls ~/.config/autostart`:

```
 4,0K -rw-r--r-- 1 user user 301 фев  6  2021 megasync.desktop
 4,0K lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user  66 фев 21  2021 touchpad-indicator-autostart.desktop -> /usr/share/touchpad-indicator/touchpad-indicator-autostart.desktop
```

Comment: It maybe caused by some session save and restore functionality inside KDE. Check these pages - https://userbase.kde.org/System_Settings/Desktop_Session and https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/plasma-desktop/kcontrol/kcmsmserver/index.html for details.

Comment: Well, it looks like that will fix it. I set it to "Start with an empty session". Will check it when I am not working. Previously it was "Restore previous session" but it was exactly the same thing every time. And I almost always close all windows before I shutdown. Strange. Thanks for the help!

Comment: These applications may have their launchers at user's config folder. Please add output of  `ls ~/.config/autostart/` to the question.

Comment: So changing it to "start with empty session" solved it. But I added the `ls` you wanted to see. Neither of the programs that were auto-opening are in there.

Comment: You can write an answer with exact steps done, to help other users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment from N0rbert solved this for me.

Just open System Settings > Startup and Shutdown > Desktop Session.

Then in the On Login box choose "Start with an empty session".

This prevents desktop session opening anything. Then I use autostart to open any other programs that I might want.